# TWEEPY import error STREAM

Tags: python, tweepy

I installed Tweepy using PIP and checked that it can be imported using Python shell
also this command works if directly put in shell `from tweepy import Stream`

But when I try to run the following lines of code, the following error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\TWITTERapp\tweepy1.py", line 1, in <module>
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
File "H:\TWITTERapp\tweepy.py", line 2, in <module>
  from tweepy import Stream
ImportError: cannot import name Stream
```

The start of the code is:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
```

Why is it not importing?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I realised I had a python file called tweepy.py and that python was trying to import Stream from that file, and obviously failing. 
So you need to change the name of the "H:\TWITTERapp\tweepy.py" file for it to work

Comment: Thanks Sal! That fixed my problem! Careless naming on my side :P